# Access nested key-values in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary structure and Iam trying to access the `total_payments` field. It is like accessing key of keys in Python dictionary:

```
d = {'METTS MARK': {'bonus': 600000,
            'deferral_payments': 'NaN',
            'deferred_income': 'NaN',
            'director_fees': 'NaN',
            'email_address': 'a@b.com',
            'exercised_stock_options': 'NaN',
            'expenses': 94299,
            'from_messages': 29,
            'from_poi_to_this_person': 38,
            'from_this_person_to_poi': 1,
            'loan_advances': 'NaN',
            'long_term_incentive': 'NaN',
            'other': 1740,
            'poi': False,
            'restricted_stock': 585062,
            'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN',
            'salary': 365788,
            'shared_receipt_with_poi': 702,
            'to_messages': 807,
            'total_payments': 1061827,
            'total_stock_value': 585062}}
```

Comment: `your_dict['METTS MARK']['total_payments']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It rather seems that values of your dictionay are dict, and not that the keys are dict.
So you can just access as follows:

```
your_dict[KEY1]['total_payments']
```

Please also anonymize the email address in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to read your dictionary, but there's an example:

```
dic = {'abc': {'123': '2'}}
print(dic['abc']['123'])

#prints 2
```

and if your dictionary had two sub dictionaries:

```
dic = {'abc': [{'123': '2'}, {'456': '4'}]}
print(dic['abc'][1]['456'])
# prints 4
```

in your case:

```
value['total_payments']

#returns 1061827
```